# R: How to load a fixed function

Tags: r, import, load

Suppose I have fixed a function using

```
fix(functionName, "path")
```

How do I load it back into my workspace?

`functionName = source("path")` doesn't seem to work, since it gives me an object with attributes:

```
$value
function (args) 
{
...
}

$visible
[1] TRUE
```

Also `load()` and `library()` don't work.

I can't find documentation on this and no earlier thread. Please help.

Comment: Please be mindful of your tags.  "fix" is for FIX protocol, not for when you need to fix something.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier I used the keyword fix because that is the name of the native R function, not because i needed to fix something. I don't see why "fix" may only refer to that specific protocol when it has a different meaning in some programming language. How should I have tagged it then?

Comment: My mistake, regarding your intent (I see a lot of newbs use it that way).  Tags on SO are used to highlight questions and/or send email alerts to people who follow certain topics (I follow "fix", for example, so I get emails when people submit "fix" questions).  I'd guess that "r" (with 4400 followers) is probably sufficient for your needs.  (I don't suspect there are a lot of people interested in getting alerts for specific functions within languages.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should already be in your workspace, but (you should see from that output that) you can also load it using:

```
functionName = source("path")$value
```

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. I left out the part where I quit R and don't want to save the workspace. Thanx very much! I guess I'm still getting used to functions being treated as objects.